# finding dimension of subspace of $P_3$ given by $H=\{a+bx^3:a,b \in \mathbb R\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm not sure how to find the dimension of this set or any set like this based on what I know about dimensions.

$H=\{a+bx^3:a,b \in \mathbb R\}$

All it seems I'm given in my notes is that $\dim(P_3) = n+1 = 4$.

Can I say something about the dimension or span of $H$ by noticing there's no $x^2$ or $x^1$?

I'm not sure, but I think if I have a set of vectors in $P_3$. I can write them vertically, then reduce and my number of non zero rows is the dimension. but I'm not sure if I can apply that to this set, all I can think of is one generalized vector $(a,0,0,b)$. How can I figure out the dimension of generalized sets (subspaces) like these?

Comment: If you can exhibit a basis for your vector space, then its dimension is the cardinality of the basis. Can you come up with a basis for H?

Comment: i'm guessing it would be {1,x^3} ?

Comment: Correct, since any element in the vector space can be written as a*1+b*x^3, where a and b are scalars, this is the most natural basis. Now we can count the number of elements in our basis, in this case two, and that gives us the dimensionality of our vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension is $2$ since any element of $H$ is expressible as a linear combination of $\{1,x^3\}$ and the set $\{1,x^3\}$ is linearly independent

Comment: so as long as H is a subspace of Pn, the dimension is the number of unique vectors in the set?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is correct, although it may be better to think in terms of basis vectors: in this case $1$ and $x^3$. Such attempt is easy to generalize, because we know that the standard basis is $\{1,x,\dots,x^n\}$.